# Select optional relationship 3 tables MySQL

Tags: mysql

Imagining the scenario of having a dropbox with UNION between tables AB and AC, but I need A to only save the entity corresponding to the selection.

How could I solve it? Simplify the problem to its minimum expression, apologies if it is not understood.

On a wider level: I have a table TASKS where tasks can correspond to TEAMS or EDILITIES but not both at the same time, I need to save only one entity, not both.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible the schema changes may solve your problem.

1. Let the table AB have foreign key of table A
2. Let the table AC have foreign key of table A
3. Let table A contain only its id and description.

I think these changes can better your schema and also helps in further processing.

Comment: And to get all the data, should I make 2 joins? I'm thinking of an object-oriented solution, since I use an ORM to get the data and I need to sit on object A

Comment: A joins AB is separate.
A joins AC is separate.

I think in ORM, it will be very easy to implement, since it is all objects.

Once you fetch the results separately, you can combine if you have a similar process ... or use separately if different processes are to be implemented.

Comment: I try test it. Thanks!